# Allow users to embed tweets using only URL

Tags: ajax, api, twitter, embed

I would like to give users the option to post tweets by entering only the url of the tweet (i.e. they would paste https://twitter.com/inspiredmag/status/342771390283411456 and then the actual tweet embed code, once received will be saved into the database to be displayed later). I'm not too familiar with the twitter api. i assume that once the user enters the url and clicks submit i will be able to get the embed code and then save it. is there a way I can grab it before submit and show a preview to the user?

Comment: First off, this is not a jQuery problem. Using common web scraping practice, you could grab the tweet directly from the URL. The standard workflow for this would be when someone pastes in the URL, you send a request to your backend, which loads the URL, scrapes the html for the tweet content, and then returns/saves that content for later use.

Comment: But, you have no tweets there `;)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out

```
<script>
$('#tweetLink').on('input', function() {
    var url = $('#tweetLink').val();
                if(url)
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/oembed.json?url="+url,
                        dataType: "jsonp",
                        async: false,
                        success: function(data){
                            $("#embedCode").val(data.html);
                            $("#preview").html(data.html)   
                        }
                    });
                }
})
</script>
```